# Namespace removal for modified element in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

I am having a input XML, in which one elements schema got changed. So as per the new schema, I renamed it.
Now for that particular element, I am getting an extra namespace in the output XML.

I used exclude prefixes, but it didnot removed. I want only that particular element which got renamed to get removed namespace. Somehow, the XSL I used before
is stripping of all the namespaces which comes at soap envelope, soap body etc, not only for the particular element.

Why only the changed element is giving namespace error. Am I giving wrong schema declaration, giving new schema for old element,(my doubt also, but change to old schema has no affect) or anyother error.
Any suggestions on this are welcome.

Format of input XML is fixed. So have to make changes only in XSLT to remove the extra namespace coming after the renamed element(PartyDetails element). All the other elements and their namespace, contracts need to be intact.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header />
    <s:Body>
    <MethodResponseType xmlns="http://example.test.com/Trialmethods/Run">
    <MessageResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ListResponse i:nil="true" />
    <OptionsResponse i:nil="true" />
    <PartyResponse>
    <DemoHolder>
    <Details>
    <ContractType>
    <ID>001</ID>
    <Name>
    <FirstName>Mano</FirstName>
    <Initial>1</Initial>
    </Name>
    </ContractType>
    </Details>
    </DemoHolder>
    </PartyResponse>
    </MessageResponse>
    </MethodResponseType>
    </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

XSLT for namespace removal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
xmlns:ns="http://example.test.com/Trialmethods/Run"
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
exclude-result-prefixes="ns xsl">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Identity template, provides default behavior that copies all content-->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- More specific template for ns:Details that provides custom behavior -->
<xsl:template match="ns:Details">
    <PartyDetails>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="strip"/>
    </PartyDetails>
</xsl:template>

<!-- template to strip out namespaces-->
 <xsl:template match="*" mode="strip">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="copy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()" mode="strip"/>
    </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output with empty namespace at renamed element.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header/>
  <s:Body>
  <MethodResponseType xmlns="http://example.test.com/Trialmethods/Run">
  <MessageResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ListResponse i:nil="true"/>
    <OptionsResponse i:nil="true"/>
    <PartyResponse>
      <DemoHolder>
        <PartyDetails xmlns=""><ContractType>
            <ID>001</ID>
            <Name>
              <FirstName>Mano</FirstName>
              <Initial>1</Initial>
            </Name>
          </ContractType></PartyDetails>
      </DemoHolder>
    </PartyResponse>
             </MessageResponse>
      </MethodResponseType>
      </s:Body>
      </s:Envelope>
```

Comment: What is the **exact** output you want to get out of the original XML input?

Comment: Hi, I want to remove the namespace coming after the modified element PartyDetails.

Comment: Didn't you put that namespace there yourself? If you don't want it, why put it there? Anyway, that doesn't answer my question. Please post the exact output you want, as code. Right now you have output before this, and output after that, and it's confusing. You seem to think that this needs to be done in two or more stages - I can see no reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to follow your question, and there seems to be some typos in your XML, XSL, but here goes...

I assume your XML input document that you are trying to translate is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <MyRequest>
            <ns:Details xmlns:ns="www.newschema">
                <ID>123</ID>
                <Name>
                    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                </Name>
            </ns:Details>
        </MyRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If the output XML you want after the translation is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <MyRequest>
            <PartyDetails>
                <ID>123</ID>
                <Name>
                    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                </Name>
            </PartyDetails>
        </MyRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Then something like the following XSLT will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ns="www.newschema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" exclude-result-prefixes="ns xsl">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity template, provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- More specific template for ns:Details that provides custom behavior -->
    <xsl:template match="ns:Details">
        <PartyDetails>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="strip"/>
        </PartyDetails>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to strip out namespaces-->
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="strip">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="copy"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()" mode="strip"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As I said you seem to have some typos in your XML/XSL

1. `xmlsns:ns` instead of `xmlns:ns`
2. `<xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">` instead of `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">`
3. `<xsl:template match="Details" ns=www.Newschema>` instead of `<xsl:template match="ns:Details">`

Ok since you've updated your question to use my XSL, I can see the `<PartyDetails xmlns="">` that you're talking about. How about the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns="http://example.test.com/Trialmethods/Run" xmlns:ns="http://example.test.com/Trialmethods/Run" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Identity template, provides default behavior that copies all content-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- More specific template for ns:Details that provides custom behavior -->
    <xsl:template match="ns:Details">
        <xsl:element name="PartyDetails">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've set the default namespace `xmlns="http://example.test.com/Trialmethods/Run"`, but you also need the `xmlns:ns="http://example.test.com/Trialmethods/Run"` for the match on `ns:Details` to work, as well as removing `ns` from the `exclude-result-prefixes="xsl"`. I've also removed the template with the strip mode.
For me this produces the output:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header/>
    <s:Body>
        <MethodResponseType xmlns="http://example.test.com/Trialmethods/Run">
            <MessageResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <ListResponse i:nil="true"/>
                <OptionsResponse i:nil="true"/>
                <PartyResponse>
                    <DemoHolder>
                        <PartyDetails>
                            <ContractType>
                                <ID>001</ID>
                                <Name>
                                    <FirstName>Mano</FirstName>
                                    <Initial>1</Initial>
                                </Name>
                            </ContractType>
                        </PartyDetails>
                    </DemoHolder>
                </PartyResponse>
            </MessageResponse>
        </MethodResponseType>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm @ptha. This is the output I am looking for. Care to explain why it worked than my solution which removes all namespaces. Thanks.

Comment: An observation. This removes namespace successfully from the elemnt, but its not populating the response as SOAP envelope. It prints outside like normal text.

Comment: Hi, how can i see the soap envelope in above xsl by @ptha. and what is the best way one can learn this concept of apply-templates and identity transformation.

Comment: @Mano, what's your input document to the XSL if it has a separate **<xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">** then that would be invalid XML. Some further info on my solution, my approach was to copy all the element (namespace included) see where I use **name()** instead of **local-name()** and then have a specific template to match the ns:Details node, and rename it to PartyDetails without a namespace.

Comment: @Mano, I've further updated my solution to use the _Identity Template_ which is more standard. For more info see http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity

Comment: Sure ptha, will definitely accept the answer. This xsl is working better, but still i am getting empty namespace in output . like <PartyDetails xmlns="">

Comment: @Mano, looks like an issue with your  input XML.`<PartyDetails xmlns="">`  means you are setting the default namespace (PartyDetails and all it's children) to the empty string. What exactly is your input XML and what XSL processor are you using? - Just update your question with this info. I'm not seeing this using Xalan.

Comment: Edited the question - kept it in easily understandable format, provided realistic input XML, XSLT from ptha and output with empty namespace.      @ptha- thanks for your help on this. I kept the ouput xml with empty namespace in edited question.

Comment: I am not using any XSL processor like Xalan. I am using stylesheets to be processed by a IBM tool Datapower. I cant control format of input I receive.

Comment: @Mano, I've updated my answer again ;) see the last XSL stylesheet, hopefully produces the same output for you. Hopefully you can accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks @ptha. Accepted the answer. Can you also tell, why previous XSLs are not successful.

Comment: Hi @Mano, I think I didn't get the correct solution (for you) straight away because I didn't have the exact same input XML as you, as well as the same XSL processor. In fact I only saw the `<PartyDetails xmlns="">` issue your were having when I changed my template to do `<xsl:element name="PartyDetails">` instead of `<PartyDetails>`. Once I was able to reproduce what you were seeing, I could see what I needed to do.